# Javascript JSON object acess error

Tags: javascript, json

I've recently been working on a phonegap application using JSONP to create a dynamic feel. I have however recently hit a bit of a brick wall...

The following function is used to parse some delivery data (irrelevant) into jquery mobile:

```
function parseProdData(results) {
    var html = '';

    for (day in results.deliveries) {
        var today = results.deliveries[day].delivery;

        var today_date_arr = today.date.split('-');
        var today_date = today_date_arr[2]+'/'+today_date_arr[1]+'/'+today_date_arr[0];

        html += '<li><a href="#">';
        html += today.delivery_day+', '+today_date;
        html += '</a></li>';
        console.log(html);
    }

    $('#JSON-list').append(html); 
    $('#JSON-list').trigger('create');    
    $('#JSON-list').listview('refresh');

}
```

Now all this looks like its working fine as when I check the console log I get:

`<li><a href="#">Thursday, 27/02/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Friday, 28/02/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Monday, 03/03/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Tuesday, 04/03/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Wednesday, 05/03/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Thursday, 06/03/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Friday, 07/03/2014</a></li>`

Thus showing that it is accessing both the date and time attributes correctly. However, straight after this I get an uncaught type error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`

From my understanding of JS this should only happen when the relevant attribute is unset. As we can see from the html output in console, this is not the case as it is being accessed correctly.

Finally, I get exactly the same error (with delivery_day as the 'undefined' attribute) if I restrict the code to just the delivery day.

For those who would like it, below is a sample of the JSON code used:

```
{
    "deliveries":[
      {
         "delivery":{
            "delivery_day":"Thursday",
            "date":"2014-02-27"
          }
      },
      {
         "delivery":{
            "delivery_day":"Friday",
            "date":"2014-02-28"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error is popping up?

****EDIT****
Just to say, I'm fairly confident that the error is in the top part rather than the JQuery mobile elements as if I comment out the block `$('#JSON-list').append(html);` with  `$('#JSON-list').append(<li><a href="#">Thursday, 27/02/2014</a></li><li><a href="#">Friday, 28/02/2014</a></li>);` then it works fine, but thats obviously not a solution.

****EDIT 2****
The issue was just that there was an empty element at the end of the 'deliveries' block, this was causing the uncaught error. I didn't notice it because the element was empty. Credit to @eithedog for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: What happens if you use `today['delivery_day']` instead?

Comment: Running your code in the console doesn't produce any errors for provided JSON object. Are you sure this has to do with this part of the code and not one of these functions: `$('#JSON-list').trigger('create'); $('#JSON-list').listview('refresh');`?

Comment: @Andy With both delivery day and date I get exactly the same response

Comment: @eithedog The code json-list etc is just appending the code onto the end of a jquery mobile <ul> with an ID of JSON-list. That code is working with straight typed html so I wouldn't think it was the issue

Comment: Either some of your JSON entries do not contain the `date` field (but that wouldn't populate your table), or there are additional triggers attached somewhere that cause the issue. Could you please comment the trigger lines and try only with appending the html for now?

Comment: I'm just taking a guess here... what is the scope of the day variable in your loop? don't you want it declared locally: for (var day in results.deliveries)? not sure if it'll make a difference though.

Comment: @eithedog I'm not 100% sure what you mean there, I have added a comment at the bottom of the original post with static html.
**ReinardMavronicolas** the day variable is just a counter, effectively its a php foreach loop if your familiar with those. TLDR; it doesn't need to be pre-declared.

Comment: The issue was just that there was an empty element at the end of the 'deliveries' block, this was causing the uncaught error. I didn't notice it because the element was empty.

Credit to @eithedog for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was just that there was an empty element at the end of the 'deliveries' block, this was causing the uncaught error. I didn't notice it because the element was empty.

Credit to @eithedog for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I saved json data in result.json file then used this

```
$.getJSON('result.json', function(result, status){
 var today =  result.deliveries;
 var html = "";
 $.each(today, function(key, value){      
   $.each(value, function(key, value){
      var today_date_arr = value.date.split('-');
      var today_date = today_date_arr[2]+'/'+today_date_arr[1]+'/'+today_date_arr[0];
      html += '<li><a href="#">'+value.delivery_day+', '+today_date+'</a></li>';          
  })
 })
  $('#JSON-list').append(html); 
  $('#JSON-list').trigger('create');    
  $('#JSON-list').listview('refresh');
})
.success(function(result) {}) 
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 }) 
.complete(function() {  });
```